# routes in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web, routes

Good Day, i'm having a trouble with the routes in Ruby on Rails 4

Error:

```
undefined method `routes_path'
```

View:

```
<h1>Load data</h1>                                
<div class="row">                       
<div class="span6 offset3">  
  `<%= form_for @route, :html => { :multipart => true } do %>  
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'current_user', @current_user %>  
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>  
    <%= submit_tag "Import", style: 'margin-top: -10px', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def new
    @route = current_user.build_route
end

def create
     nil_flag = Route.import(params[:file], current_user)
    if nil_flag == 1
      flash[:success] = "Data created."
      redirect_to route_path(current_user)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error"
      redirect_to load_data_path
    end
end
```

Model:

```
def self.import(file, current_user)
   @user = current_user
   @route = @user.build_route
   @nil_flag = 0

   File.open(file.path, 'r') do |f|
   .
   .
   .
    #etc
end
```

Routes

> match '/load_data', to: 'routes#new', via: 'get'

Views, controller and model are named "Route"

Is a problem with the route in the view or something else? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt (the previous answer author) pretty much answered the question, just want to notice that you can also append the `as` option to your route to give it a name:

`match '/load_data', to: 'routes#new', via: 'get', as: 'routes'`

this will "define" the `routes_path` for you.

Comment: It's not an ideal solution, it's a lazy one. No offense, but this is just compounding the issue with more complexity, especially since the method is still a `get`!

Comment: True, I absolutely agree with that

Answer (score 3):

Just as a first impression, without looking into it in detail - you may have trouble using routes as a class name, it's already a class name under `ActionDispatch`.

However, I think your problem is actually your route:

```
match '/load_data', to: 'routes#new', via: 'get'
```

This isn't a resource route, it won't generate the kind of functionality that allows you to use the form tag syntax `<%= form_for @route...`

Either define routes as a resource:

```
resources :routes
```

Or define a url in your form:

```
<%= form_for @route, :url => some_url, :html => { :multipart => true } do %>
```

Comment: this means we cannot use routes with some action, this will call the core class with given action?

Comment: There is a lot of control over routes that you can see examples of within the routes file itself. You can define specific routes for a collection of `Route`s or you can define member method routes, the point is you have an ActiveRecord resource in your project named `Route` and you will have a much easier time if you do things the rails way, using proper routing. Have a read of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default to help explain what I'm saying.

Comment: @fahadIdrees See my comment above, and also on Vlad's answer.